# Ubuntu 16.04 (16.10), stuttering desktop changing

Tags: 16.04, graphics, intel-graphics, gui, performance

I am experiencing a bit stuttering (laggy) animation during desktops switching, and overall GUI feels not very responsive.
A few curious points, that made me ask question here:

1. My PC is quite powerful (Skylake 6700K, Samsung 950 PRO SSD, 32 GB RAM) and I expect animations to be more smooth.
2. Yes, it **does lack** GPU, however:

   1. It used to be *much* better, but at some point something happened and I started to experience those issues. I'm pretty sure that it wasn't some faulty software or misconfiguration of system.
   2. I have totally similar PC right here (we have similar workstations here, at my work) and animations are *noticable* better. That was confirmed by several people, so it's not my imagination.
3. Recently I gave up on fixing it and reinstalled Ubuntu, and fresh installation *gave me similar* issues.
4. I have upgraded to 16.10 hoping that will fix it, but it didn't.
5. I have installed Intel Graphics Update Utility and have updated graphics drivers using it, but it didn't helped either.

I have totally no idea what is happening or how to diagnose issue. My current hypothesis is that my hardware messing up (as issue persisted among full reinstallation of system), but I don't know how to narrow the scope even a little bit.

To help you a little more, I've recorded [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzHH6hgWvJY&feature=youtu.be) with those issues. **That's not video issues**, in real life it looks pretty much similar.

I'll be grateful for any advices and response!

Comment: Have you looked in the "software and updates > additional drivers" settings to see if proprietary drivers are actually being used after installing the Intel drivers ?

Comment: @linuxbun Yep, it says i'm using some proprietary driver for my CPU. "Unknown: Unknown" seems a bit fishy though. Here is a details: [Software and Updates](https://s18.postimg.org/guthvf5nt/Screenshot_from_2016_10_21_17_08_19.png)

Comment: The drivers installed with the Intel tools are also open-source and just a slightly newer minor revision compared to the default ones shipped with Ubuntu. No improvement should be expected and it shouldn't make the list of proprietary driers anyway. Skylake used to require additional Grub parameters but I don't know if that is still applicable to the latter 16.04 or 16.10 kernels.